# Select an image from pictures gallery

Tags: windows-phone-7, picturegallery

I want to let users to get an image from their picture library (place where pictures taken with camera are) to use as an Avatar in my app. Or maybe, I can add some images to XAP file.

My questions are:

1. What must I do to let user select a picture from its picture library?
2. What must I do to let user select an image added to XAP?

Answer (score 3):

### 1) Use `PhotoChooserTask` or `MediaLibrary`

- [Windows Phone 7 - Selecting device photos without (and without) PhotoChooserTask](http://andy-teamg.blogspot.com/2010/07/windows-phone-7-selecting-device-photos.html)

### 2) Use `ResourceManager` with `Resource URIs` (AKA `Pack URIs`)

- [Silverlight 2: Demystifying URI references for app resources](http://nerddawg.blogspot.com/2008/03/silverlight-2-demystifying-uri.html)
- [Resource Files in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc296240%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: How can I get a list of available images of a folder? If I add some images to folder /Assets/Images. How can I get all Uri for those images?